# Meaning of "Lucy’s papa that it was a nuisance"

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature

> Still eight but almost nine, Lucy had made friends that summer with the
> O’Reillys’ dog. A big, frolicsome animal – half setter, half retriever – it
> had crept into the O’Reillys’ yard a month or so ago, having wandered
> from a deserted house – so Henry’s guess was – and been accepted after
> some hostility by the O’Reillys’ working dogs. Henry said it was a useless
> creature, **Lucy’s papa that it was a nuisance**, particularly the way it
> scrambled down the cliffs to offer its company to whoever might be on the
> strand. The O’Reillys had given the dog no name and would hardly have
> noticed – so Henry said – if it had wandered off again. When Lucy and her
> papa had their early-morning swim, her papa always sent it back when he
> saw it bounding over the shingle.

Does it mean: Lucy’s papa had said that it was a nuisance?

Or does it mean: the dog made trouble for Lucy’s papa?

Source: *The Story Of Lucy Gault* by William Trevor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Henry said it was a useless creature, Lucy’s papa that it was a nuisance.

This means that:

- Henry **said** it was a useless creature
- Lucy’s papa **said** that it was a nuisance

The word "said" is not required twice in this phrasing.